# load image with asset in twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig

i want to load an image in my twig but it doesnt show anything only show picture alt

this is my list.html.twig that will load image:

```
<img src="{{ asset('images/2.jpg') }}" alt="Symfony" />
```

and this is my controller :

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class InheritanceController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/inherit")
     */
    public function inheritAction(){
        return new Response($this->render('article/list.html.twig'));
    }
}
```

my image folder is in root directory

Comment: what do you mean by root directory ? can you show or describe your files architecture ?

Comment: @t-n-y root directory in symfony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `asset()` function in twig with its default configuration only when your images exists on `web/images` folder, then you can make a call to any image by `{{ asset('images/<image_name>') }}`

Answer (score 0):

Install assets via console: `php app/console assets:install --symlink`

Answer (score 0):

The method `$this->render()` already returns a `Response` instance, just change it to`return $this->render(...)` and try again.